# how to increase form width

Tags: c#, winforms, autoresize, window-resize

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this, But imagine some 2d game like this
[image: Some 2d game]
sooner or later this guy is going to reach the end of the form(if the form isn't redrawn/ extended),hence how do I Redraw the background when the guys reaches the middle of the current form so our character can in sense, walk for ever. Think of those 2d running games like flappy bird or jetpack joyride where you can walk or fly for infinity. Additionally, the form size is only altered when the character moves.

Comment: you wouldn't increase the form width, you would start moving the background to the left instead of the player image to the right.

Comment: and how would I do that?

Comment: O, that seems.... easy

Comment: nvm, how do I move the background?

Comment: show the code you have so far and the part that's giving you trouble. questions that begin with *"imagine some 2d game ..."* won't get any real replies, because we're just imagining. Instead, you should show what you've tried and describe specifically how it's not working. Specifically check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code that ive tried creating isn't really effective, like it doesn't work to a beneficial point, I can post it if you want but can you at least give me the concept by which one moves the background

Comment: In the old good days when you can use managed direct x this was easy done. But now with c# and vb you need sharp DX or c/c++ with native direct x to do that staff. In general winforms isn't a good idea for a 2d game.

Comment: But there is an alternative solution which is using GDI. The timer need to be set at no more than10msec.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude way to do it, hopefully it helps get you going. Basically just create a picture box as tall as your form and twice as wide, load your background image into it, and then, in a timer, move the picture to the left. You'll need a very wide image, and it will look a little jerky at the transition unless you make the last "frame" match the first one.

Changing the amount that you subtract from the left will control how fast it scrolls, so I named that variable "speed".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int scrollSpeed = 10;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private PictureBox backgroundPictureBox;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Width = 1000;
        Height = 1000;

        backgroundPictureBox = new PictureBox
        {
            BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
            Height = this.Height,
            Image = Image.FromFile(@"f:\Public\Temp\tmp.png"),
            Left = 0,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            Visible = true,
            Width = this.Width * 2
        };
        Controls.Add(backgroundPictureBox);

        timer.Interval = 1;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundPictureBox.Left < (Width * -1))
        {
            backgroundPictureBox.Left = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundPictureBox.Left -= scrollSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```